# mashing 2D domain and streamplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

can someone tell me how can i get mesh for domain showed in picture below?

this is example of meshing simple rectangular domain

```
x_start, x_end = 0. , 10.
y_start , y_end = 0. , 8.
i = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, 80)
j = np.linspace(y_start, y_end, 50)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(i,j)

Dx = x_end/(np.size(i)-1)
Dy = y_end/(np.size(j)-1)
beta = Dx/Dy
nx = np.size(i) 
ny = np.size(j) 

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

How can i get mesh grid only for this rectangular domain:

[image: rectangular domain]

Comment: Create an outer rectangle and filter the ones you don't want using boolean indexing https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a clear description of the desired output? Looking at the plot one would probably just shift half the y coordintes by 1, but how can we know?

Comment: sorry if Im not make it clear enough, but yes, I should move y coordinate for 1 like in plot

Comment: @Joe but how to set the rectangle to remove unnecessarily parts using indexing?

Comment: You need to apply two separate operations, one for the left and one for the right part. You could also use polygon clipping but this would really be to complex for the task at hand.https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Polygon3/3.0.8

Answer (score 1):

To shift part of the grid by a constant amount, you can just add a constant,

```
Y[:,:40] += 1
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_start, x_end = 0. , 10.
y_start , y_end = 0. , 8.
i = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, 80)
j = np.linspace(y_start, y_end, 50)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(i,j)
Y[:,:40] += 1

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X,Y, color="grey", lw=0.72)
plt.plot(X.T,Y.T, color="grey", lw=0.72)
plt.show()
```